# Changing a Windows Phone Application's WritableBitmap Object

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, image-capture

All, I have a basic Windows 7 Phone application and I have just finished a crop page, where the users are able to crop an image taken with the phones camera. In the `cameraCapTask_Completed` event I set the App's global `WritableBitmap`

```
public static WriteableBitmap capturedImage;
```

as follows

```
void cameraCapTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
    {
        // Take JPEG stream and decode into a WriteableBitmap object.
        App.capturedImage = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);
```

When I take a picture I then pass it to the cropping page in the `CropProcessPage` constructor I set the Image in the page via

```
public CropProcessPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set the text and display captured image.
    imageMain.Source = App.capturedImage;
```

This works. However, when I go back to the Main Page and retake/take another image, when I try to the new image, the old image (the first one taken) is shown. The constructor is being called and so is the camera captured event (setting the new image). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: when I try to the new image, the old image (the first one taken) is shown. so dispose it ;)

Comment: I have attempted to do this but there is, ofcourse, no `Dispose()` method; so what do I do? Use `Invalidate()` if so, how?

Comment: what about null? define it null at global stage

Comment: Doesn't work. I have set it to null before I reassign. It is as if once the App object (WritableBitmap) is set, it can't be changed!?

Comment: yea this is bug i think.. so delete App.capturedImage use only imageMain.Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CropProcessPage

move  line

```
imageMain.Source = App.capturedImage;
```

to

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
// Set the text and display captured image.
    imageMain.Source = App.capturedImage;
}
```

Comment: I have found that the displayed image when using the emulator is always the same. Perhaps I shuld have said this in the question; that is, I am using the emulater to capture images. In this case is this a common error/feature of the editor? Sorry if I have wasted your time.